# How to add borders to GTK2 boxes?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I would like to add a border to an HBox in GTK2.
I have tried wrapping the HBox in a GtkFrame, and while that works, the border is too thin for my needs and I could not find how to change that.
If this is possible, it would be an option.

Another approach I tried was wrapping the HBox in an EventBox and then coloring the EventBox's background to emulate a border.
Here, I ran into the problem that setting the EventBox's background color propagated the setting to the HBox itself.
If there is a way forward with this approach, it might be preferable, because of the added benefit of color choice (that said, if we can change GtkFrame's border color that might be work great too).

EDIT: I have reached something very close to what I'm looking for after managing to change the color of the GtkFrame surrounding the box only.
Still, I'd like to make the frame colored border a bit thicker and have not had much luck.

EDIT²: I have managed by essentially sandwiching two EventBoxes. I change the background color of the outer box and then change the background color of the inner box to match the default background. In this scenario, thickness can be controlled by the border width setting of the box.

[image]

Comment: try using gtk-inspector.. it shows you all the properties related to the widget

Comment: @SivaGuru I managed to do it!

Comment: if you solved the problem then you could post the answer. it might help someone who faces the same issue.

Comment: @SivaGuru I have edited the main question with the approach I used, is it advisable to answer my own question all the same?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with answering your own question.